# How to get info related to collectionView selected cell from xml file, then print to tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have built a calendar using JTAppleCalendar dependency (its a collectionView) and have a tableview on the bottom same screen. I want to select a date in the calendar, then find the date in an xml file and print its accompanying holiday event in the tableView.

I am using an XML Parser to get the dates and holiday event and I can parse and print the xml data to my console. Currently the whole xml file is printing in the tableview, but I want to only print the date selected from the calendarView. I'm getting confused thinking about how to make the date selected equal to the xml date and then print only that to the tableview, and need some help with this step.

Here is my full code for the calender view controller:

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!
@IBOutlet weak var year: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var month: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var separatorViewTopConstraing: NSLayoutConstraint!

let outsideMonthColor = UIColor.cyan
let monthColor = UIColor.white
let selectedMonthColor = UIColor.darkGray
let currentDateSelectedViewColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
let todaysDefaultDateColor  = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let todaysDate = Date()
let numOfRowsInCalendar = 6

var tableViewDataSource = [CalendarDates]()
var calendarevent = ""
var monthTableview = ""
var dateTableview = ""
var datenumberTableview = ""
var holidayTableview = ""
var descriptionTableview = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCalendarViewAtStart()
    setUpTableViewAtStart()
    setUpBackgroundView()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}

//Mark: Calendar View JTApple code
func setupCalendarViewAtStart(){
    //Scroll to today's date at start
    calendarView.scrollToDate(todaysDate, animateScroll:false)
    calendarView.selectDates([todaysDate])
    //Setup calendar spacing
    calendarView.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    calendarView.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    //Setup labels
    self.calendarView.visibleDates { visibleDates in
        self.setupViewsOfCalendar(from: visibleDates)
    }
    self.adjustCalendarViewHeight()
}

func handleCellTextColor(view: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    guard let validCell = view as? CalendarCell else { return }

    if cellState.isSelected {
        validCell.dateLabel.textColor = currentDateSelectedViewColor
    } else {
        if cellState.dateBelongsTo == .thisMonth {
            validCell.dateLabel.textColor = monthColor
        } else {
            validCell.dateLabel.textColor = outsideMonthColor
        }

    validCell.isHidden = cellState.dateBelongsTo == .thisMonth ? false : true
    }
    //today's date selection
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    let todaysDateString = formatter.string(from: todaysDate)
    let monthDateString = formatter.string(from: cellState.date)
    if todaysDateString == monthDateString {
        validCell.dateLabel.textColor = todaysDefaultDateColor
        validCell.dateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
    } else {
        validCell.dateLabel.textColor = monthColor
        validCell.dateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
    }
}

func handleCellSelected(view: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    guard let validCell = view as? CalendarCell else { return }
    if validCell.isSelected {
        validCell.selectedView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        validCell.selectedView.isHidden = true
    }
}

func setupViewsOfCalendar(from visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {
    let date = visibleDates.monthDates.first!.date
    self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
    self.year.text = self.formatter.string(from: date)
    self.formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    self.month.text = self.formatter.string(from: date)
}

//Mark: TableView setup
func setUpTableViewAtStart() {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    self.tableView.bounces = true

    if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "calendar", withExtension: "xml")
    {
        if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
}
}

//Mark: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource

extension CalendarViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {

func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

    let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2018 08 01")!
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2019 01 31")!
    let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                             endDate: endDate,
                                             numberOfRows: numOfRowsInCalendar)
    return parameters
}
}

//Mark: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate

extension CalendarViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate {
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplay cell: JTAppleCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

//Display the cell
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
    let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell

    cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text

    handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)

    return cell
}

func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
}

func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didDeselectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
}

}

//Mark: TableView Delegate/DataSource for Date and Holiday Names

extension CalendarViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return dateTableview.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "\(dateTableview)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableViewDataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalendarDateEvent", for: indexPath)

    let holidayTableviewLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    holidayTableviewLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].holiday

    let dataTableviewLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    dataTableviewLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].datenumber

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2773199975, green: 0.3366781473, blue: 0.3707436919, alpha: 1)
    header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
}

//Mark: XML Parse Delegate

extension CalendarViewController {
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    calendarevent = elementName
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if data.count != 0 {
        switch calendarevent
        {
        case "month": monthTableview = data
        case "date": dateTableview = data
        case "datenumber": datenumberTableview = data
        case "holiday": holidayTableview = data
        default: break
        }
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == "calendarevent"
    {
        var myCalendarDates = CalendarDates()
        myCalendarDates.month = monthTableview
        myCalendarDates.date = dateTableview
        myCalendarDates.datenumber = datenumberTableview
        myCalendarDates.holiday = holidayTableview

        //print(myCalendarDates)
        tableViewDataSource.append(myCalendarDates)
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Calendar struct:

```
struct CalendarDates {
var month = ""
var date = ""
var datenumber = ""
    var holiday = ""
    var description = "" }
```

My XML file has a structure like:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
< calendar>
    < calendarmonth id= "August">
        < calendarevent>
            < month>August</month>
            < date>August 20, 2018</date>
            < datenumber>20</datenumber>
            < event>
                < holiday>First Holiday</holiday>
            < /event>
            < event>
                < holiday>Second Holiday</holiday>
            < /event>
        </calendarevent>
        <calendarevent>
            <month>August</month>
            <date>August 26, 2018</date>
            <datenumber>26</datenumber>
            <event>
                <holiday>Third Holiday</holiday>
                <description>ccccccccccc</description>
            </event>
        </calendarevent>
    < /calendarmonth>
< /calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

> Step 1: In this function you will get the date which user selected from the Calendar.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) { ... }
```

> Step 2: Write a logic which will find out the data which matches to your XML result.

```
func findOutResult(matchesToDate date: Date) -> [Result] {...}
```

> Step 3: Reload your table and it should display the required result.

Since you have written the logic for Calendar, TableView, it should be easy for you.

Comment: Thank you. Step 2 is the part I've been struggling with all day. I can get the entire xml code to print in my tableView cells when the view runs, like this - https://imgur.com/a/lbK1QUP but I'm struggling with matching the date in the xml to the date selected, specifically with how to pick the "keys" for data at the row

Comment: I suggest you create a dictionary forming each date from the selected month as a key and holds the bunch of data for that particular date. So for example: when you scroll to a month in JTAppleCalendar let's say it's August. So you have to update your dictionary with following 01-Aug-2018 to 31-Aug-2018 these all dates will be used as a key holds records for the particular dates in form of `[Result]`. Now from step-1 you will get the date, just convert the date to a string value to create a key for that month: So if I select 15 Aug 2018 from the calendar, my key will be 15-Aug-2018.

Comment: then I simply have to check for that key in the dictionary and I will have the `[Results]` array if available, next follow step-3.